# Browserify cannot find module even though it exists

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I've recently started to use node, gulp, and browserify for a new project and keep running into the same issue. I typically have 'gulp watch' running while I'm making changes. The problem is that I'll be working on a file and need to create and require a new file. So I'll go ahead and write the require line before I've created the file. When I save it, gulp runs and of course browserify throws an error since the file doesn't exist yet. No problem. Then I'll create and save the missing file. Gulp runs again and browserify STILL throws an error that the file doesn't exist. But I know the file exists.

It is not a path issue. If I duplicate the file and name it something else and then change the require statement to point to the new file, it works fine.

There must be some sort of caching going on here. If I leave the project and come back to it a few hours later, it sorts itself out. How can I force it to resolve the file right when I create it?

Comment: Could you include your Browserify and watch tasks in your question?